# Can I serve blank pages to facebook crawler?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, web-crawler

I have a site with thousand of pages crawled by `facebookexternalhit` bot.

Can I identify this bot, and serve just the `<head>` section with the `og` tags of my page?

Making this, I save some money with bandwidth and database access...

So my question is: What is the impact if I do it? Facebook needs to know what my site has inside the `<body>` tag?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, provided there's a full set of meta tags served to Facebook's crawler there doesn't nee to be any other content: this is the similar to the 'pointers' functionality which is the recommended method for some edge-cases in Open Graph sharing:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/using-metadata-pointers

Answer (score -1):

According to them:

> Facebook allows its users to send links to interesting web content to
>   other Facebook users. Part of how this works on the Facebook system
>   involves the temporary display of certain images or details related to
>   the web content, such as the title of the web page or the embed tag of
>   a video. Our system retrieves this information only after a user
>   provides us with a link. You may have found this page because a
>   Facebook user sent a link from your website to other Facebook users.
>   If you have any questions or concerns about any links or content sent
>   by one of our users, please contact us at legal@facebook.com.

Basically if you do what you propose (and it'd be easy with a combination of RewriteCond and one extra QUERY_STRING param) you'll remove the possibility for Facebook to retrieve the meta info they need to build their nice post when an user insert a link in a chat, a private message, or a post.

I would rather try to understand if and when a certain page is hit multiple times in a short period since this shouldn't be the case.

Comment: All tags that facebook need to show the informations at the timeline, is provided by the `<head>` tag. So, if I have a blank `<body>`, facebook can show the beautiful post... My concerned is if they use the site content to do other things, like a web search engine...

Comment: This is not fully true since Facebook scans the page for alternate images that may be found in the body. I'm not aware of any indexing activity carried by them. I just checked the log of an high traffic website I manage and I've noticed very few hits compared to other spiders.